# MSBuild Command script not publishing font files correctly

Tags: iis-7, command-line, msbuild, teamcity

I'm using an msbuild command line script to publish a c# web project from team city out to a live server.

After wrestling with IIS perimisions etc it all works well...

....apart from the fact that the font files end up not being copied to the right directory (they end up on the bin directory)

```
/t:rebuild 
/p:Configuration=Deploy 
/p:OutputPath=bin 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<server>/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:username=<username>
/p:password=<password>
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=<sitename> 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

Any suggestions as wo what I can do to force the files to go to the right directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the fonts are included as "Content" by right clicking on them in Visual Studio and selecting properties and changing the "Build Action" to "Content". Also ensure "Copy to output directory" is set to "Do not copy"